# Using an autonumber field as an external Id for API upsert

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, rest-api

Can I use an autonumber field as an external Id for API upsert?

Answer (score 2):

You can not actually do that, but what you can do is create an external field, and an autonumber field. Then create a workflow that fills the external ID field by the autonumber field value :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would still cause upsert problems. You'd almost need a trigger to manage the current autonumber value.

Comment: I am using Camel salesforce rest API  , I have a custom object Called Ra_Message__c. I am using the Patch api call /services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Ra_Message__c/External_Id__c/R****1800000** : it is returning the following error. {message:'Error {400:Bad Request} executing {PATCH:/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Ra_Message__c/External_Id__c/R****1800000*}',statusCode:400}

Comment: @sfdcfox if the external ID gets sets after creation of the record using the workflow I think the autonumber(Salesforce) should be set then. Unless I haven't understood what exactly OP needs.